# React JSX - make substring in bold

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While creating custom autocomplete component I stuck with this problem: I got a string and substring(first part of the string, the one that user enters in autocompete field), and I need to show that part in bold in results list.

But I cannot use `str.replace` like

```
    var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
    return str.replace(re, '<b>'+find+'</b>');
```

because it will return string and I need JSX.

So basically the problem is - I have JSX and I need to make some part of it in bold. I need a function that takes JSX and like inject `<b>` tag in it in special places

This is what I got so far

```
    boldJSX(str, find){
        if(!find) return str;
        return <span><b>{find}</b>{str.slice(find.length)}</span>
    }
```

Comment: do you have some code? tried anything? Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: of course I have tried before asking. I tried to use string functions , but I need it for JSX to work

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/bvaughn/react-highlight-words

Comment: so, add it to to your question and then we can help you

Comment: I added the function I came up with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to find and extract the appropriate substring (the string you are looking for) if exits in given list and make a custom string by extracting that substring as given below.

```
 //autoValue - value you are looking for
 //main - item value
 const val =
  main.slice(0, main.indexOf(autoValue)) +
  "<b>" +
  autoValue +
  "</b>" +
  main.slice(
    main.indexOf(autoValue) + autoValue.length,
    main.length
  );
```

Now, You have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` for a `span` or any custom `HTML` component you are using for rendering each item in you auto-complete component.
Here is full example.

```
const items = [
 "React",
 "Angular",
 "Vue",
 "Node",
 "Express",
 "PHP",
 "Laravel",
 "Material",
 "CSS",
 "HTML"
];

function ListItem(props) {
 if (props.value.indexOf(props.autoValue) > -1 && props.autoValue.length > 0) {
 const main = props.value;
 const val =
  main.slice(0, main.indexOf(props.autoValue)) +
  "<b>" +
  props.autoValue +
  "</b>" +
  main.slice(
    main.indexOf(props.autoValue) + props.autoValue.length,
    main.length
  );

 return (
  <div>
    <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: val }} />
    <hr />
  </div>
);
} else {
return (
  <span>
    {props.value}
    <hr />
  </span>
 );
 }
}

function NumberList(props) {
 const numbers = props.numbers;
 const listItems = numbers.map(number => (
  <ListItem
   key={number.toString()}
   value={number}
   autoValue={props.autoValue}
  />
 ));
 return <div>{listItems}</div>;
}

class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   inputValue: ""
 };

 this.update = this.update.bind(this);
}

update(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
}

render() {
 return (
   <div>
     <input
       type="text"
       onChange={this.update}
       name="inputValue"
       value={this.state.inputValue}
     />
     <NumberList numbers={items} autoValue={this.state.inputValue} />
     <span> {this.state.inputValue} </span>
   </div>
 );
 }
 } 

export default App;
```

Working Example. https://codesandbox.io/s/n9n65wqj5j

Comment: dangerouslySetInnerHTML ... sounds a little dangerous to use :)

Comment: It's wrapper around innerHTML. https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Answer (score 21):

I seem to have found a more 'reactish' approach for those who come here in the future

```js
function BoldedText({ text, shouldBeBold }) {
  const textArray = text.split(shouldBeBold);
  return (
    <span>
      {textArray.map((item, index) => (
        <>
          {item}
          {index !== textArray.length - 1 && (
            <b>{shouldBeBold}</b>
          )}
        </>
      ))}
    </span>
);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: This gives me a warning:

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the top-level render call using <span>. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding upon @mantas-giniūnas solution, I've enhanced it to maintain letter-casing.

```
function BoldedText({ text, shouldBeBold }) {
  const textArray = text.split(RegExp(shouldBeBold, "ig"));
  const match = text.match(RegExp(shouldBeBold, "ig"));

  return (
    <span>
      {textArray.map((item, index) => (
        <>
          {item}
          {index !== textArray.length - 1 && match && (
            <b>{match[index]}</b>
          )}
        </>
      ))}
    </span>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already know that the suggestion passed in matches the filter you can do

```
getSuggestionText = (suggestion, filter) => (
  <span>
    <b>{suggestion.slice(0, filter.length}</b>
    {suggestion.slice(filter.length)}
  </span>
);
```